# Get and save the date in a struct C

Tags: c, date, struct, char

I have something like this:

```
void set_email_date()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
    strcpy(email.date, tm.tm_mday"-"tm.tm_month+1"-"tm.tm_year +1900);
}
```

I know it terribly wrong but I have tried 1000 different thinks and none of them worked.
I want to store it following this structure `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Comment: Have you tried `strftime`?

Comment: Use `snprintf`.

Comment: "I have tried 1000 different thinks" and only 1 non-compilable one posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tm.tm_mday"-"tm.tm_month+1"-"tm.tm_year +1900
```

This is not how you create string.

```
char date[100];
sprintf(date, "%02d-%02d-%d\n", tm.tm_day, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_year + 1900);
strcpy(email.date, date);
```

An this would only work if `email.date` is an array with enough space or if you
have already dynamically allocated memory with `malloc` & friends. Without
seeing how you did it, it's only a guess.

But you could also use `strftime` to format the date.

> [*man strftime*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)
>
> ```
> #include <time.h>
>
> size_t strftime(char *s, size_t max, const char *format,
>                        const struct tm *tm);
> ```
>
> *DESCRIPTION*
>
> The `strftime()` function formats the broken-down time tm according to the format specification format and places the result in the character
>   array s of size `max`.  The broken-down time structure tm is defined in `<time.h>`.  See also [ctime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime).

Because we don't know that how you initialized `email.date` and which is its
type, I'm going to assume that is a `char[20]` or something.

```
strftime(email.date, sizeof email.date, "%d-%m-%Y", &tm);
```